# How to force RESTEasy (Wildfly 8.2) to use UTF8?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, jboss, resteasy, wildfly-8

I'm building up a REST service with RESTEasy to use in Wildfly 8.2. This basically works but it's not UTF-8.

My configuration looks like this:
[image: wildfly encoding]

I use the automatic JaxRs activation of Wildfly by generation this empty class which causes RESTEasy to work:

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class JaxRsActivator extends Application
{
}
```

My REST implementation looks like this:

```
@Path("/user")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class UserResource
{
    @GET
    @Path("/{firstname}-{lastname}")
    public Response printMessage(@PathParam("firstname") String param1, @PathParam("lastname") String param2)
    {
        return Response.ok().entity(new TestObject(param1, param2)).build();
    }
}
```

When I invoke this resource by

```
http://localhost:8080/mywebserver/rest/user/Déborah-François
```

I get as a result:

```
{"name1":"DÃ©borah","name2":"FranÃ§ois"}
```

The delivered encoding is windows-1252. Why is this so? I want UTF-8 configured on Wildfly.

**[UPDATE]**
It doesn't even work when I add this into jboss-web.xml:

```
<default-encoding>UTF-8</default-encoding>
```

(I don't understand why UTF-8 is not default at all. In my opinion this is a must have)

Comment: Referring to why UTF-8 is not the default. AFAIK there is no standard which  specifies to use UTF-8 for URIs. The common way is to use ISO-8859-1 and url-encode all characters which don't fit in this charset.

Comment: I tried to set the `<default-encoding>` in the jboss-web.xml as well as in the standalone.xml as [described here](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-2533?focusedCommentId=12933050&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-12933050) but without effect. I tried it with Wildfly 8.1.0.Final. Maybe you could try it with the fix version (8.0.0.CR1) and see if it works there?

Comment: @lefloh When I create a test client and send an UTF-8 request to my server, the encoding works on the response output.

Comment: What do you mean with "create a test client"? Maybe this client url-encodes the utf-8 characters?

Comment: @lefloh I wrote a simple Java class which can send a request encoded as UTF-8 to my webserver. The response was properly encoded.

Comment: Question is what this class is really sending: `/user/Déborah` or `/user/D%C3%A9borah`?

Comment: @lefloh I can tell you in the evening. What I can say for sure: When I tried both the unencoded and encoded string as URL in browser, in both cases I got a wrongly encoded result. The result is only ok when I invoked it by my Java class.

Comment: You need to take a look what really is being sent. For instance: If you put https://www.google.com/?q=Déborah in the address bar of your browser and watch the Network Tab of your developer tools you will most probably see that the browser is sending ?q=D%C3%A9borah.

Answer (score 1):

The browser/HTTP client sends the URL, evidently as UTF-8, but it does not tell so. Hence the HTTP default encoding ISO-8859-1 is used.

In JBoss a stand-alone server might be configured in standalone.xml as:

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.USE_BODY_ENCODING_FOR_QUERY_STRING"
        value="true"/>
</system-properties>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. Same result, encoding stay windows-1252. I made the configuration in Admin console to be sure to not position it in the wrong place within standalone.xml

Comment: Wildfly is using Undertow so setting setting Tomcat properties doesn't work anymore.

Comment: this is for jboss as 7, wildfly doesn't use apache catalina anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The problem maybe doesn't exist. I will explain, I have the following situation:

when I test a form on localhost (wildfly 8.x) it doesn't work, both display and write do break characters. But when i build a project.war from the same sourcecode and send to a test server, everything works fine.

I tested any language i could, taking the most different ones: chinese, ucrainian (cyrillic), greek, left-to-right and right-to-left languages, even in the same word and it works.

Try to test your project sending your .war on a test server.

Comment: Currently I don't have the problem anymore, because I have no use case where I pass such parameters. I pass whole objects to the endpoint. These objects itself contain attributes with any language. It seems to return the correct values in response as well as it stores the correct encodings into the database.